# What should be the number of functions with this condition.

Tags: functions, transfinite-recursion

The condition is very simple $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the domain of a function $f(x)$.

We have to find total number of $f(x)$ such that  $fof(x)=x$.

Obviously, It means that $f$ ought to be inverse of itself. What i tried was Making pairs of elements in Domain and then seeing total such possible mappings.

Example: Let $(1,2) and (3,4)$ be the respective pairs and they end up with mapping $\{1\rightarrow2 and 2\rightarrow1 \}$ or $\{2\rightarrow2 and 1\rightarrow1 \}$  and same case with $(3,4)$

This should be giving me an answer of $^4C_2*2=12$
But my book says it's 13. Please someone explain my error or provide a better and elegant method for the same.

Comment: What about the function $x \mapsto x$?

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid, but I can only see $10$. There is the identity function; $6$ functions of the form $a\mapsto b \mapsto a, c\mapsto c, d\mapsto d$; and $3$ functions of the form $a\mapsto b \mapsto a, c\mapsto d\mapsto c$.

Comment: @TonyK My book can be wrong. Please elaborate in Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea but forgot the identity function.

Comment: Me and my brain #facepalm. thanks anyways